# Need to create an API for Drupal 7 website (location, cck, node reference)

Tags: api, blackberry, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I have a drupal 7 website and am having a bb app developed. I need to create an api that will allow the app to get conditional data from drupal database. The drupal 7 site is comprised of 2 content types that link to each other, (catalogues and specials), cck fields (price, image etc), and taxonomy terms (via tagging). I know there are readily available modules such as services, but the developers say service module installed is not much of our help, it is given general data, doesnt allow them to do selected queries, so they have to work on getting data as per app requirements (which results in the having to bill for a custom solution)... Im just wondering if there is not another option available I might have missed, or a simpler way to accomplish this? What about a conditional view with arguments that they can filter to get their results? Sorry for my ignorance, just have no idea how this works

Comment: The Services module _is_ the solution. If  the out-of-the-box stuff doesn't do what you need, you'll need to write custom resources. It's very easy to do, there are code examples in the Services module itself

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help 
http://tylerfrankenstein.com/code/android-app-with-drupal-7-services-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile

If no,
Can you more details what exactly you need to do?